# Как три разных метода синхронно запустить и вообще возможно ли это? Может быть я не совсем правильно выражаюсь, но надеюсь смысл понятен

Tags: c#

Решаю задачу о ферзях: Найти все мирные расстановки N ферзей на шахматной доске N на N. Занимаюсь оптимизацией моего решения.

```
private static int CalculatePeacefulArrangement(int queenCount, int[] chessTable, int startPosition, int result)
    {
        if (startPosition == chessTable.Length)
        {
            result++;
            return result;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < queenCount; i++)
        {
            var index = Array.IndexOf(chessTable, 0, startPosition + i, queenCount - i);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                var row = index - startPosition;
                NoteBeatenCellAscendingDiagonal(queenCount, chessTable, index, 1);
                NoteBeatenCellDiscendingDiagonal(queenCount, chessTable, index, 1);
                NoteBeatenCellHorizontal(queenCount, chessTable, index, row, 1);
                result = CalculatePeacefulArrangement(queenCount, chessTable, startPosition + queenCount, result);
                NoteBeatenCellAscendingDiagonal(queenCount, chessTable, index, -1);
                NoteBeatenCellDiscendingDiagonal(queenCount, chessTable, index, -1);
                NoteBeatenCellHorizontal(queenCount, chessTable, index, row, -1);
                i = row;
            }
            else break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void NoteBeatenCellHorizontal(int queenCount, int[] chessTable, int index, int row, int marking)
    {
        var column = index / queenCount;
        for (int i = column; i < queenCount; i++)
        {
            chessTable[i * queenCount + row] += marking;
        }
    }
    private static void NoteBeatenCellAscendingDiagonal(int queenCount, int[] chessTable, int index, int marking)
    {
        for (int i = index; i < chessTable.Length; i += queenCount + 1)
        {
            chessTable[i] += marking;
            if (i / queenCount == queenCount - 1 || i % queenCount == queenCount - 1) break;
        }
    }
    private static void NoteBeatenCellDiscendingDiagonal(int queenCount, int[] chessTable, int index, int marking)
    {
        for (int i = index; i < chessTable.Length; i += queenCount - 1)
        {
            chessTable[i] += marking;
            if (i / queenCount == queenCount - 1 || i % queenCount == 0) break;
        }
    }
```

Пробовал через `Parallel.Invoke`. И через `Task[] tasks`, циклом запуская все. При массиве задач ждал выполнения всех через `Task.WaitAll(tasks)`. Но уже даже на 4 ферзях может выдавать разные ответы. Может все таки я неправильно понял сам принцип параллельного программирования(если так можно назвать)?
**Если вы просто знаете алгоритм лучше моего, пожалуйста, не надо мне его спойлерить**

Comment: Parallel.For - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @АртемийГордон на странице, что вам скинули, если её открыть, то внизу будут примеры.

Comment: хм, а вы уверены, что распараллеливание вам подойдет? Не будет проблем с тем, что вы одновременно будете читать и писать в разделяемое состояние (доску)

Comment: @tym32167 в моем понимании я запущу три заполнения одновременно: горизонталь, восходящая диагональ, нисходящая диагональ, поэтому не вижу ничего в этом плохого

Comment: @Igor Можете, пожалуйста, расписать как его использовать. Читал про него, но не понял как применить к моему коду. Названия перегрузок слишком несовместимы с тем, что я хочу сделать. А вот Invoke по описанию очень подходит, даже отладчиком просматривал первые шаги - все нормально работает, но в итоге все равно где-то происходит неправильное действие

Comment: @tym32167 зайдя на ту страницу снова не нашел мне подходящего, а вот про Invoke написано то, что мне нужно

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, у вас есть 2 метода

```
void PrintA()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Console.WriteLine($"A {i}");
}

void PrintB()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) Console.WriteLine($"B {i}");
}
```

Чтобы запустить их параллельно, можно написать такой код:

```
var taskA = Task.Run(()=>PrintA());
var taskB = Task.Run(()=>PrintB());

Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB);
```

Тут мы запускаем 2 задачи и потом ждем, когда они обе закончатся.

Но, имейте ввиду, что так как у вас подзадачи очень маленькие, то абсолютно не факт, что такая оптимизация позволит вам ускорить алгоритм.

Comment: Можете объяснить почему `task.start` не работает, а также в чем проблема `Parallel.Invoke`? Судя по описанию из документации он просто создан для моей проблемы.

Comment: кстати, ваш способ не рабочий, работает только так `Task[] tasks1 = new Task[3]
{
    new Task(() => NoteBeatenCellAscendingDiagonal(queenCount, chessTable, index, 1)),
    new Task(() => NoteBeatenCellDiscendingDiagonal(queenCount, chessTable, index, 1)),
    new Task(() => NoteBeatenCellHorizontal(queenCount, chessTable, index, row, 1))
};
                    foreach (var t in tasks1)
                        t.RunSynchronously();
                    Task.WaitAll(tasks1);`
Но я не уверен, что эти методы работают параллельно

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что потоки могли обратиться к одинаковым элементам

Решение:

```
private static void NoteBeatenCellHorizontal(int queenCount, int[] chessTable, int startPosition, int row, int marking, int index)
    {
        for (int i = startPosition / queenCount + 1; i < queenCount; i++)
        {
            chessTable[i * queenCount + row] += marking;
        }
    }

    private static void NoteBeatenCellDiscendingDiagonal(int queenCount, int[] chessTable, int row, int marking, int index)
    {
        if (row != 0)
            for (int i = index + queenCount - 1; i < chessTable.Length; i += queenCount - 1)
            {
                chessTable[i] += marking;
                if (i / queenCount == queenCount - 1 || i % queenCount == 0) break;
            }
    }

    private static void NoteBeatenCellAscendingDiagonal(int queenCount, int[] chessTable, int row, int marking, int index)
    {
        if (row != queenCount - 1)
            for (int i = index + queenCount + 1; i < chessTable.Length; i += queenCount + 1)
            {
                chessTable[i] += marking;
                if (i / queenCount == queenCount - 1 || i % queenCount == queenCount - 1) break;
            }
    }
```